# T-Sql - Issue setting SQL Agent Database Mail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, database-mail

So, for SQL 2008 R2 or below, when looking in:

- SQL Server Agent Properties

  - Alert System

    - Mail System

I see SQLMail (Urrggghh) and Database Mail (hurrah)

When I use `msdb.dbo.sp_set_sqlagent_properties` against SQL 2008 R2, I cannot use the `@use_databasemail` parameter as this is only valid from SQL 2012.

So, the question is, do any of you know how to set the Mail System to use Database Mail using T-SQL? I’ve tried and failed!

I really don’t want to have to do this manually as the scripts I’ve written will be going out to field engineers. Everything else works like a dream, except for this!

I thought of using the code below BUT, this caters for default instances, not named instances:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regwrite
     N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent',
     N'UseDatabaseMail',N'REG_DWORD', 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a bit more work i realised that the below code does in fact work as its based on the connection / instance. My code takes into account the sql version number.

```
USE [msdb];
GO

DECLARE @ProductVersion varchar(128) = CONVERT(varchar(128), SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion'));
--Do this if the sql version is SQL 2008R2 or below
IF left(@ProductVersion,2) <11
     --Set the sql agent to use Database Mail and not SQLMail
     EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent', N'UseDatabaseMail', N'REG_DWORD', 1;
IF left(@ProductVersion,2) <11
     --Set sql agent to use the 'MyDBMailProfile' mail profile
     EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent', N'DatabaseMailProfile', N'REG_SZ', N'MyDBMailProfile;

ELSE
--Do this if the sql version is above SQL 2008R2
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_set_sqlagent_properties 
        @databasemail_profile=N'MyDBMailProfile', 
        @use_databasemail=1;
GO
```